# How to display a progress indicator in pure C/C++ (cout/printf)?

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, c++11, io

I'm writing a console program in C++ to download a large file. I know the file size, and I start a work thread to download it. I want to show a progress indicator to make it look cooler.

How can I display different strings at different times, but at the same position, in cout or printf?

Comment: checkout the PDCurses library http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/

Comment: [C++ Console Progress Indicator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424948/c-console-progress-indicator) might help

Comment: Spawning a `wget` process is not an option ?

Comment: [tag:curses] ... [tag:ncurses]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewinding std::cout to go back to the beginning of a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057977/rewinding-stdcout-to-go-back-to-the-beginning-of-a-line)

Comment: Just curious, how are you downloading the file? What libraries/other are you using?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

With a fixed width of your output, use something like the following:

```
float progress = 0.0;
while (progress < 1.0) {
    int barWidth = 70;

    std::cout << "[";
    int pos = barWidth * progress;
    for (int i = 0; i < barWidth; ++i) {
        if (i < pos) std::cout << "=";
        else if (i == pos) std::cout << ">";
        else std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "] " << int(progress * 100.0) << " %\r";
    std::cout.flush();

    progress += 0.16; // for demonstration only
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

http://ideone.com/Yg8NKj

```
[>                                                                     ] 0 %
[===========>                                                          ] 15 %
[======================>                                               ] 31 %
[=================================>                                    ] 47 %
[============================================>                         ] 63 %
[========================================================>             ] 80 %
[===================================================================>  ] 96 %
```

Note that this output is *shown* one line below each other, but in a terminal emulator (I think also in Windows command line) it will be printed *on the same line*.

At the very end, don't forget to print a newline before printing more stuff.

If you want to remove the bar at the end, you have to overwrite it with spaces, to print something shorter like for example `"Done."`.

Also, the same can of course be done using `printf` in C; adapting the code above should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 71):

For a `C` solution with an adjustable progress bar width, you can use the following:

```
#define PBSTR "||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
#define PBWIDTH 60

void printProgress(double percentage) {
    int val = (int) (percentage * 100);
    int lpad = (int) (percentage * PBWIDTH);
    int rpad = PBWIDTH - lpad;
    printf("\r%3d%% [%.*s%*s]", val, lpad, PBSTR, rpad, "");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

It will output something like this:

```
 75% [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||               ]
```

Comment: Watch out, there should be no `';'` at the end of the first `#define`!

Comment: This is the simplest and best solution I have found so far

Comment: Is there a way to display an ascii character instead of | ? Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of the last part, why is there a `""` for the last argument of the `printf()` ?

Comment: @Sylvain The string in the square brackets has two parts; left and right. The left part consists of `lpad` characters of `PBSTR` printed using the `%.*s` specifier, while the right part consists of `rpad` length of a space left-padded string which we chose to be empty "" so that we only print `rpad` spaces using the `%*s` specifier.

Comment: Oh the right side is already "space left-padded". Thanks !! Great solution indeed.

Comment: I think "percentage" parameter name is misleading as the function expects fraction of one  ie. 0.1, 0.2, 0.5 and so on, not the percentage ie. 10.0, 20.0, 50.0.

Answer (score 66):

You can use a "carriage return" (\r) without a line-feed (\n), and hope your console does the right thing.

Comment: + manual flush, otherwise it will not be shown immediately because the output is buffered.

Comment: And if the user accidentaly hits the enter it breaks down :( Apart from that, it is perhaps the most portable solution, +1.

Comment: @Ali To avoid that, you would have to disable echoing (see [`man termios`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios))

Comment: @leemes `#include <termios.h>`, try that on M$ Windows :) Anyway, thanks for the tip, I will probably try that on Linux.

Comment: @Ali There might be an equivalent for W1ndOw$, but I don't know it. ;)

Comment: Using `"\r\e[0K"` could also help clean the line. (tested under linux)

Answer (score 14):

You can print a carriage return character (`\r`) to move the output "cursor" back to the beginning of the current line.

For a more sophisticated approach, take a look at something like ncurses (an API for console text-based interfaces).

Comment: + manual flush, otherwise it will not be shown immediately because the output is buffered.

Comment: + `'\b'` for moving the cursor one position left.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at boost progress_display

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/timer/doc/original_timer.html#Class%20progress_display

I think it may do what you need and I believe it is a header only library so nothing to link

Answer (score 7):

I know I am a bit late in answering this question, but I made [a simple class that does exactly what you want.](https://github.com/ETCG/pBar) (keep in mind that I wrote `using namespace std;` before this.):

```
class pBar {
public:
    void update(double newProgress) {
        currentProgress += newProgress;
        amountOfFiller = (int)((currentProgress / neededProgress)*(double)pBarLength);
    }
    void print() {
        currUpdateVal %= pBarUpdater.length();
        cout << "\r" //Bring cursor to start of line
            << firstPartOfpBar; //Print out first part of pBar
        for (int a = 0; a < amountOfFiller; a++) { //Print out current progress
            cout << pBarFiller;
        }
        cout << pBarUpdater[currUpdateVal];
        for (int b = 0; b < pBarLength - amountOfFiller; b++) { //Print out spaces
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << lastPartOfpBar //Print out last part of progress bar
            << " (" << (int)(100*(currentProgress/neededProgress)) << "%)" //This just prints out the percent
            << flush;
        currUpdateVal += 1;
    }
    std::string firstPartOfpBar = "[", //Change these at will (that is why I made them public)
        lastPartOfpBar = "]",
        pBarFiller = "|",
        pBarUpdater = "/-\\|";
private:
    int amountOfFiller,
        pBarLength = 50, //I would recommend NOT changing this
        currUpdateVal = 0; //Do not change
    double currentProgress = 0, //Do not change
        neededProgress = 100; //I would recommend NOT changing this
};
```

An example on how to use:

```
int main() {
    //Setup:
    pBar bar;
    //Main loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //This can be any loop, but I just made this as an example
        //Update pBar:
        bar.update(1); //How much new progress was added (only needed when new progress was added)
        //Print pBar:
        bar.print(); //This should be called more frequently than it is in this demo (you'll have to see what looks best for your program)
        sleep(1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I made all of the classes' strings public so the bar's appearance can be easily changed.

Answer (score 5):

Another way could be showing the "Dots" or any character you want .The below code  will print progress indicator [sort of loading...]as dots every after 1 sec.

PS : I am using sleep here. Think twice if performance is concern.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Will load in 10 Sec " << endl << "Loading ";
    for(count;count < 10; ++count){
        cout << ". " ;
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    cout << endl << "Done" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple one I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   // Changing text color (GetStdHandle(-11), colorcode)
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(-11), 14);
   
   int barl = 20;
   cout << "[";     
   for (int i = 0; i < barl; i++) {         
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
      cout << ":";  
   }
   cout << "]";

   // Reset color
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(-11), 7);
}
```

Comment: You don't use system() and especially the color command. Use `SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, color)` instead and don't forget to reset (color 7).

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you can just use string's [fill constructor](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

```cpp
#include <iostream> //for `cout` and flush
#include <string>   //for the constructor
#include <iomanip>  //for `setprecision`

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int cTotalLength = 10;
    float lProgress = 0.3;
    cout << 
        "\r[" <<                                            //'\r' aka carriage return should move printer's cursor back at the beginning of the current line
            string(cTotalLength * lProgress, 'X') <<        //printing filled part
            string(cTotalLength * (1 - lProgress), '-') <<  //printing empty part
        "] " <<
        setprecision(3) << 100 * lProgress << "%" <<        //printing percentage
        flush;
    return 0;
}
```

Which would print:

```bash
[XXX-------] 30%
```

If you need it in pure C

and you would like to be able to customize the size and filler characters at runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //for `printf` and `fflush`
#include <stdlib.h> //for `malloc`
#include <string.h> //for `memset`

int main()
{
    const int cTotalLength = 10;
    char* lBuffer = malloc((cTotalLength + 1) * sizeof *lBuffer); //array to fit 10 chars + '\0'
    lBuffer[cTotalLength] = '\0'; //terminating it
    
    float lProgress = 0.3;

    int lFilledLength = lProgress * cTotalLength;
    
    memset(lBuffer, 'X', lFilledLength); //filling filled part
    memset(lBuffer + lFilledLength, '-', cTotalLength - lFilledLength); //filling empty part
    printf("\r[%s] %.1f%%", lBuffer, lProgress * 100); //same princip as with the CPP method

    //or you can combine it to a single line if you want to flex ;)
    //printf("\r[%s] %.1f%%", (char*)memset(memset(lBuffer, 'X', lFullLength) + lFullLength, '-', cTotalLength - lFullLength) - lFullLength, lProgress * 100);
    fflush(stdout); //streams are usually buffered and not get printed until you send `\n` or "flush" it

    free(lBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

but if you don't need to customize it at runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //for `printf` and `fflush`
#include <stddef.h> //for `size_t`

int main()
{
    const char cFilled[] = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    const char cEmpty[]  = "----------";
    float lProgress = 0.3;
    
    size_t lFilledStart = (sizeof cFilled - 1) * (1 - lProgress);
    size_t lEmptyStart  = (sizeof cFilled - 1) * lProgress;

    printf("\r[%s%s] %.1f%%",
        cFilled + lFilledStart, //Array of Xs starting at `cTotalLength * (1 - lProgress)` (`cTotalLength * lProgress` characters remaining to EOS)
        cEmpty  + lEmptyStart,  //Array of -s starting at `cTotalLength * lProgress`...
        lProgress * 100 //Percentage
    );
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create a progress bar and some of the answers here would cause the bar to blink or display the percentage short of 100% when done. Here is a version that has no loop other than one that simulates cpu work, it only prints when the next progress unit is incremented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // for setw, setprecision, setfill
#include <chrono>
#include <thread> // simulate work on cpu

int main()
{
    int batch_size = 4000;
    int num_bars = 50;
    int batch_per_bar = batch_size / num_bars;

    int progress = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; i++) {
        if (i % batch_per_bar == 0) {    
            std::cout << std::setprecision(3) <<
                      // fill bar with = up to current progress
                      '[' << std::setfill('=') << std::setw(progress) << '>'
                      // fill the rest of the bar with spaces
                      << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(num_bars - progress + 1)
                      // display bar percentage, \r brings it back to the beginning
                      << ']' << std::setw(3) << ((i + 1) * 100 / batch_size) << '%'
                      << "\r";
            progress++;
        }
        
        // simulate work
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1000000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My very simple C solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)
#define PBWIDTH 64
#define PBCHAR '#'
static void progressbar(unsigned percent) {
  char pbstr[PBWIDTH];
  memset(pbstr, PBCHAR, PBWIDTH);
  fprintf(stderr, "\r[%-" S(PBWIDTH) ".*s] %u%%",
      percent * PBWIDTH / 100, pbstr, percent);
}
int main(void) {
  progressbar(70);
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

Outputs:

```
[############################################                    ] 70%
```

The `memset` should be optimized to 1 or 2 vector instructions when compiled for modern CPUs, much smaller than storing the whole string statically and equally fast.

In the programs I use it in, I like to print 0% this way, before the loop that calls `progressbar`:

```c
fprintf(stderr, "[%-" S(PBWIDTH) ".*s] %u%%", 0, "", 0);
```

---

If you prefer the number to be before the bar, change the `fprintf` in `progressbar`:

```c
  fprintf(stderr, "\r%3u%% [%-" S(PBWIDTH) ".*s]",
      percent, percent * PBWIDTH / 100, pbstr);
```

And if you do the optional 0% bit:

```c
fprintf(stderr, "%3u%% [%-" S(PBWIDTH) ".*s]", 0, 0, "");
```

Modify this all as you see fit. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will helps you -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void show_progress_bar(int time, const std::string &message, char symbol)
{
    std::string progress_bar;
    const double progress_level = 1.42;

    std::cout << message << "\n\n";

    for (double percentage = 0; percentage <= 100; percentage += progress_level)
    {
        progress_bar.insert(0, 1, symbol);
        std::cout << "\r [" << std::ceil(percentage) << '%' << "] " << progress_bar;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time));       
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    show_progress_bar(100, "progress" , '#');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide an internative method using std::setfill() and std::setw().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

static void printProgressBar(int percent, int progressWidth=60)
{
    std::cout << "\r[" << std::setfill('#') << std::setw(percent*progressWidth/100) << '#';
    std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(progressWidth*(100-percent)/100) << "]";
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << percent << "%";
    std::cout.flush();
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    
    for (int i=0; i<=100; i+=1)
    {
        printProgressBar(i, 100);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(20ms);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```